# Which nosql database for heterogeneous records?

Tags: database, nosql, ravendb, log-analysis

I'm looking at different options for storing log entries for easier querying/reporting.
Currently I write scripts that parse and find the data, but the data is becoming more and more in demand, so it's becoming worth it to put the log data in a database.

Log entries are composed of key-value pairs, such as`{"timestamp":"2012-04-24 12:34:56.789", "Msg":"OK"` (simplified example).
I'm sure that eventually the log format will be extended to, say `{"timestamp":"2012-04-24 12:34:56.789", "Msg":"OK", "Hostname":"Bubba"`, which means that the "schema" or "document definition" will need to change. Also, we're a Windows + .NET shop.

Hence, I was primarily looking for some NoSQL engine and found RavenDB attractive to use from .NET.
However, I have a hard time finding information about how it, and other NoSQL databases, work with heterogeneous records.
What would be a good fit in your opinion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With RavenDB you can just store the different types of docs and it will be able to handle the "changes" in schema. Because it is in fact "schema-free", you can write indexes that will only index the fields that are there. See [this blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/66563/ravendb-migrations-rolling-updates) for some extra info. It's talking about migrations, but the same applies here.

Also the [dynamic fields](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/dynamic-fields) option will help you here. So given doc with arbitrary properties:

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

You can write queries like this:

```
var logs = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<LogEntry>("LogEntry/ByAttribute")
    .WhereEquals("Msg", "OK")
    .ToList();
```